# Programmer productivity with STL vs. custom utility classes

Tags: c++, stl

I work in an environment where, for historical reasons, we are using a hodgepodge of custom utility classes, most of which were written before STL arrived on the scene. There are many reasons why I think it is a good idea to at least write new code using STL, but the main one is that I believe it increases programmer productivity. Unfortunately, that is a point that I don't know how to prove.

Are there any studies out there that attempt to quantify, or even just hint at, a productivity gain from using STL?

**Update:** I guess I should have been more specific. I am *not* advocating rewriting existing code, and I am *not* worried about the new hires that will get a running start. The former would be foolish, and the latter by itself is not enough to convince people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no studies that will show STL is more productive just because it is STL. Productivity gains from using it are due to it being a standard programmers are familiar with it, and because the code is already written and tested.

If your company already has utility classes that employees are familiar with, and this utility code is used throughout an existing codebase, then switching to STL could actually be detrimental to productivity.

That said for new code using STL would be a good move. I would not necessarily argue this from a productivity standpoint, but one of maintainability. If you have code that predates STL it sounds like code at your company has quite a long lifetime and is likely to be maintained by a number of new programmers over the years.

You may also want to broach the use of STL as a way for everyone to keep their C++ skillset sharp. While I wouldn't reject a C++ candidate who didn't know STL, I would definitely view it as a black mark.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the STL is so "good" is simply because it's been around a long time now and the implementations have seen a lot of users and eyes.  They're well debugged and the algorithms have been pretty well optimized by vendors.

STL will be more productive for new devs in your shop because it's likely they are already familiar with it.  Your custom libs will be foreign and probably lacking in features that devs are accustomed to using.  That's not a huge issue after the initial ramp-up period for new devs though.

There's no real pressing reason to shift to STL just because it is.  If you have perfectly useful utility classes in your application I'd recommend sticking with them unless they're not workable for new code.  Mixing STL with your custom libraries in new code is going to cause compatibility problems at some point and refactoring the code to use all STL is going to introduce bugs.  Either way you'll be losing productivity.

Edit:  By "new" code, I mean new code in existing applications using the older class libraries.

If you're developing new standalone apps that do not draw on any of the old applicaiton code I'd recommend STL because it's there, most every C++ dev knows how to use it and it's pretty stable (and you get support from your toolset vendor if it's not).

Answer (score 2):

I think the critical factor is the turnover rate of the development team.

If the team is stable, and they've been working on this code for ten years and probably will be ten years from now, they will be more productive using the utility classes they're familiar with, and nudging them to use the STL will result in reduced productivity and bugs.

If the team turns over a lot, then the new developers will likely be familiar with the STL, and obviously not this proprietary utility class library, and will do better with the STL.

Answer (score 2):

The only argument for increasing productivity with STL I can think of would be a possibility of integrating other libraries easily - Boost, Arabica, SOCI, etc. They are all designed to work with STL, not your in-house container classes.

Answer (score 2):

I have been in the same situation. It depends on the utility classes in question. Many custom utility classes I have seen have been buggy, or poorly designed, and are causing bugs and inefficiencies throughout the source. In this case, a straight replacement with STL equivalents will improve the codebase, increase productivity, decrease bugs and reduce maintainance costs for the future.

You can sometimes help to bridge the gap between the two worlds by retrofitting STL-style iterators to your old classes, though be careful to get them right!

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the reverse is true where the home-grown utilities are in any way domain-specific to the work you do.

Answer (score 1):

One place where STL is useful is not in the actual libraries etc that are provide by STL but rather in the coding style that STL uses.

In the following there are 2 main tests required:

```
struct DoSomething {
  bool operator ()(Container::value_type const & v) const
  {
    // ...
  }
};

void bar (Container const & c)
{
  std::for_each (c.begin (), c.end (), DoSomething ());
}
```

The first tests verify that 'DoSomething::operator()' does what it's supposed to do.  The second test only needs to verify that 'DoSomething::operator()' is called.

This separation can help improve productivity when compared with a hand written for loop.  For the above, the number of tests is the sum of the "thing to be done" and the tests that the call is made for a non empty container.  In the case of the for loop the number of tests is the product of the tests.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons I see are:

### Quality of the code

The writers of the STL (either its interface, or the implementation for your compilers) are without doubts magnitudes better than the best developer in your company.

Their job is to make a usable STL, which means that every function/method/object is heavily tested anyway.

### Maintainability of the code

With the turnover, some code can become slowly and stealthily unmaintained. Which means that if there is a bug in this code, or if its performance or interface are found lacking (see the "Quality" above), then you'll find no one to expertly improve it.

The code change will have a non-zero probability of a code regression elsewhere, and if your in-house library is not unit-tested, that this regression will go undetected for quite some time.

And I'm not even mentioning the "I WON'T ever touch that slimy code" syndrome when someone trying to correct the code just finds he doesn't understand why it was done this way (because of macros, strange pre-conditions, etc..

### Conclusion

Combine the two, and you'll find that for generic code (i.e. arrays, strings, etc.), you'll go better by slowly migrating from in-house libraries to STL library, writting "converter functions" when needed.

I think this kind of migration is part of the maintenance of your code, and that you should slowly (i.e. with new code, or when refactoring), whenever possible, use STL instead of in-house generic libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the utility classes, there's no need for using the STL. It will quickly become a maintainability problem as you find the need to begin integrating the STL into your utility libraries. IMO, it will be a productivity **loss**.

That said, the STL may offer a lot of features and utilities that your utility libraries don't provide. (Particularly useful is the <algorithms> header, which you can probably begin using immediately without many problems with legacy code.) If you're writing a lot of new code, it's far better to use the STL (and Boost, if you can) than to write your own utility classes and algorithms. As a result, it will be a major productivity gain.

I don't know of any studies on the topic, though.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the situation when you hire a new C++ programmer. Is s/he more likely to have experience with STL classes or your own ones? You could be looking at huge savings in time before they become productive if you start to switch to the STL.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, any newly hired employee will have to learn how to use the old classes, and that costs time and money. Using STL like everyone else would save your company money and keep it attractive among the pool of candidates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to justify replacing these custom classes wholesale, unfortunately. If possible, replace them with STL components a class at at time.

This is a maintenance & readability issue as much as anything. (1) Using STL helps maintainers understand the code at a glance, versus needeing to learn their way around custom implementations. (2) The STL is WELL documented and well understood - what about your custom classes? (3) The STL is well vetted. (4) The STL comes with asymptotic runtime upper & lower bounds.

Good luck.